# CSS preferred height with maximum height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` that should have a maximum height and a preferred height. In the sample posted below, I have `#test` with a black background and a maximum height of `800px`. When the browser view-port has sufficient available space, it should take `800px`. If less space is available (i.e. mobile devices), the maximum amount of available space should be used. How can this be achieved with preferably just CSS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Prototype</title>
        <style>
            body, html {
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #test {
                background-color: black;
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                max-height: 600px;
                max-width: 800px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also include the following attributes to `#test`:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

Fiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nx5Zb/

With embedded full-page result: http://jsfiddle.net/Nx5Zb/embedded/result/

Comment: Simple and elegant! Thanks! I will accept this answer in 9 minutes :-)